# В многострочных сообщениях чата игнорируется Markdown-разметка

Tags: дефект, чат, форматирование, markdown

Если в сообщении чата присутствует символ перевода строки, форматирование игнорируется и отображается как есть, будто чат не использует Markdown. // *Chat message formatting sequences are ignored if a message contains a new line character, so that sequences are displayed as is (as if a chat engine does not use Markdown).*

Пример для воспроизведения ошибки // *A case for reproduction*:

> ```
> Проверка форматирования многострочных комментариев: 
> **жирный** *курсив* 
>
> [ссылка 1](example.com). [ссылка 2](example.com)
> ```

Отображение [сообщения](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43203106#43203106) производится следующим образом: // *This message is rendered in the following way:*

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия обозревателя // *Version of a browser I use:* Chromium 60.0.3112.113 (x32 build for Windows).

Comment: Статус так-задумано?

Comment: @AK, с чего бы вдруг? В справке к чату эта особенность вроде бы не описана, значит она не была запланирована.

Comment: Firefox 52 ESR - тоже не работает. Похоже, что так во всех браузерах. Потому и говорю, что это легализованный баг.

Comment: Поддержу, хотелось бы юзать MD и в многострочном режиме.

Comment: [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/282647) - так задумано